# On AJAX call HTML design changes?

Tags: php, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I am working on php and MySQL. I want to display number and address of selected user. I used AJAX from another page. and my query works fine. I am able to display data of selected user.

But problem is when I select user it's data not going on right labels. I will show you how it looks and also show you my code for this.

Before selection from dropdown:

[image: Before selection from dropdown]

After selection from dropdown:

[image: After selection from dropdown]

My code for before submit data:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 3%;" class="col-md-12">                   
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: -2%;">
      <label>GSTIN</label>
        <label  name="gstn" class="control-label" value="" id="state-list1">
    </div>                                                        
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 3%;" class="col-md-12">                   
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-top: -5%;">
      <label>Billing Address</label>
        <label  name="billingAddress" id="state-list" class="control-label demoInputBox"  value="">
    </div>                                     
</div>
```

code after ajax call:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['customer_name'])) 
{ 
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT  customer_locations.address , customer_locations.state ,customer_locations.custLocId, customer_locations.city , customer_locations.pin , customer_locations.locality, customer_locations.gstNo ,customer_master.defaultBilling , customer_master.defaultsupply FROM customer_locations INNER JOIN customer_master ON customer_locations.customerId = customer_master.customerId WHERE customer_master.customerId = '" . $_POST["customer_name"] . "'");
  ?>  
  <?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>
    <label value="<?php echo $row["custLocId"];?>"><?php echo $row['gstNo'];?></label><br>
<?php }}?>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['customer_name'])) 
{ $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT  customer_locations.address , customer_locations.state , customer_locations.custLocId ,customer_locations.city , customer_locations.pin , customer_locations.locality, customer_locations.gstNo ,customer_master.defaultBilling , customer_master.defaultsupply FROM customer_locations INNER JOIN customer_master ON customer_locations.customerId = customer_master.customerId WHERE customer_master.customerId = '" . $_POST["customer_name"] . "'"); 
  ?>  
  <?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?><label value="<?php echo $row["custLocId"];?>"><?php echo $row['defaultBilling'];?></label>
<?php }}?>
```

Script for ajax call:

```
function getState(val) {
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "demogroup1.php",
      data:'customer_name='+val,
      success: function(data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
        $("#state-list1").html(data);
      }
      });
    }
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Please google how to use prepared statements and parameterised queries with mysqli, in order to better protect yourself. At the moment your code is wide open to hacking by sending a malicious value (e.g. for the customer name) which could allow someone to steal, corrupt or delete your data.

Comment: Well for starters, what is the actual HTML that you are sending back from the AJAX Call response?

Comment: @amit Here you either have to output together Gstn and Billing address from ajax page and replace the whole div content.Or you have to use output having content type json and only fill the required html field.

Comment: how to do with content type json @deffrinjoseph. can you provide me code

Comment: @amitsutar: it's worth noting that _Stack Overflow_ is not a clearing house for free labour. Readers are happy to help, but they generally will not (and should not) do it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ajax call

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['customer_name'])) 
{ 

  // For escaping special characters
  $customer_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["customer_name"]);
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT  customer_locations.address , customer_locations.state ,customer_locations.custLocId, customer_locations.city , customer_locations.pin , customer_locations.locality, customer_locations.gstNo ,customer_master.defaultBilling , customer_master.defaultsupply 
    FROM customer_locations INNER JOIN customer_master ON customer_locations.customerId = customer_master.customerId 
    WHERE customer_master.customerId = '" . $customer_name . "'");

  // Since we only fetch a single users data we dont need to use while loop
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


  $data=array(
    'custLocId'=>$row["custLocId"],
    'gstNo'=>$row['gstNo'],
    'defaultBilling'=>$row['defaultBilling']
    );

  header("Content-type:application/json");
  echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Script for ajax call

```
function getState(val) {
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "demogroup1.php",
      data:'customer_name='+val,
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data){
        $("#state-list1").html(data.gstNo);
        $("#state-list").html(data.defaultBilling);
      }
      });
    }
```